# How to save standard object in custom controller?

Tags: apex, visualforce, standard-objects, custom-controller

I want to create a form which when submitted will then create a record in Lead object. But I'm unable to fetch the values submitted by the user. Where am I going wrong?

*Apex Class*

```
public class SimpleClass {
    public Lead lead {get;set;}

    public PageReference save() {
        System.debug(lead); //Output - null
        return null;
    }
}
```

*VF Page*

```
<apex:page controller="SimpleClass">
    <apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Enter Details">
       <apex:inputField value="{!lead.firstName}" label="First Name"/>
       <br/>
       <apex:inputField value="{!lead.lastName}" label="Last Name"/>
       <br/>
       <apex:inputField value="{!lead.company}" label="Company"/>
       <br/>
       <apex:inputField value="{!lead.email}" label="Email"/>
       <br/>
       <apex:inputField value="{!lead.phone}" label="Phone"/>
       <br/>
       <apex:commandButton value="Submit" action="{!save}" />
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, I needed to instantiate the `lead` object. Hence, I did that in the constructor.

```
public SimpleClass() {
    lead = new Lead();
}
```

Comment: You can close your question as well with selecting best answer.It could be yours too.

Comment: cool! I didn't know that :)

Answer (score 1):

So to create a Lead record into the database, you need to insert that record. The save method could be like this,

```
public class SimpleClass {
public Lead lead {get;set;}

public SimpleClass (){
    lead = new Lead();
}

public PageReference save() {
    try {
        insert lead; // DML statement to insert Lead record
    } catch (DmlException e) {
        // Process exception here
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

```
<apex:page controller="SimpleClass">
    <apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Enter Details">
       <apex:inputField value="{!lead.firstName}" label="First Name"/>
       <br/>
       <apex:inputField value="{!lead.lastName}" label="Last Name"/>
       <br/>
       <apex:inputField value="{!lead.company}" label="Company"/>
       <br/>
       <apex:inputField value="{!lead.email}" label="Email"/>
       <br/>
       <apex:inputField value="{!lead.phone}" label="Phone"/>
       <br/>
       <apex:commandButton value="Submit" action="{!save}" />
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Try this code, I am able to create to Lead record using above code.
[Apex DML Operations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dml_section.htm)

Comment: But the value of `lead` is NULL. It throws an error if i use `insert lead`. Refer my answer below, i needed to instantiate the object.

Comment: Updated Apex class and visualforce code. Try this code, hope it will work for you !